# Node process often loses CPU time on Linux VM which increases latencies for client requests

Tags: node.js, linux, virtual-machine

**Problem** - Increase in latencies ( p90 > 30s ) for a simple WebSocket server hosted on VM.

**Repro**

Run a simple [websocket server](https://github.com/websockets/ws#simple-server) on a single VM. The server simply receives a request and then upgrades it to websocket without any logic. The client will continuously send 50 parallel requests for a period of 5 mins ( so approximately 3000 requests ).

**Issue**

Most requests have a latency of the range 100ms-2s. However, for 300-500 requests, we observe that latencies are high ( 10-40s with p90 greater than 30s ) while some have TCP timeouts (Linux default timeout of 127s).

When analyzing the VM processes, we observe that when requests are taking a lot of time, the node process loses it CPU share in favor of some processes started by the VM.

**Further Debugging**

- Increasing process priority (renice) and i/o priority (ionice) did not solve the problem
- Increasing cores and memories to 8 core, 32 GiB memory did not solve the problem.

**Edit - 1**

Repro Code ( clustering enabled ) - https://gist.github.com/Sid200026/3b506a9f77cfce3fa4efdd1ec9dd29bc

[image: Latency data after using clustering]

When monitoring active processes via htop, we find that the processes started by the following commands are causing an issue

```
python3 -u bin/WALinuxAgent-2.9.0.4-py2.7.egg -run-exthandlers
```

```
/usr/lib/linux-tools/5.15.0-1031-azure/hv_kvp_daemon -n
```

Comment: "some processes started by the VM" which?

Comment: How are you clustering the ws server process?

Comment: Added as edit-1